# What is this lambda routing constraint doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I ran across this code in the Split gem's instructions.

To restrict access to the dashboard route, they recommended:

```
match "/split" => Split::Dashboard, :anchor => false, :constraints => lambda { |request|
  request.env['warden'].authenticated? # are we authenticated?
  request.env['warden'].authenticate! # authenticate if not already
  request.env['warden'].user.admin?
}
```

I know that the :constraint key makes it such that if the lambda returns false, then the route is unavailable (at least, that's what I think).

But what is the point of the first line? And the second? I don't understand why calling an `authenticated?` method would do anything. And what does `authenticate!` do?

Comment: https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/overview#the-how

Comment: @MichaelKohl, well that answers the second question, but why include the first line `.authenticated?`?

Comment: Given the order of the two statements, I'd assume `authenticated?` will set some internal object state which will cause `authenticate!` to not run if the user is already authenticated. After all the above wiki link states "This lazy object allows you to interact with it to ask if it’s authenticated or to force authentication to occur in any downstream piece of Rack machinery."

Comment: @MichaelKohl That's what I thought as well, although it would be pretty strange if true.